# Ед. или мн. число глагола?

Tags: орфография

"Основу регулирования таких вопросов составляЕ(Ю)т Закон о здравоохранении, а также Закон о санитарно-эпидемиологическом благополучии".

Как правильно? Поначалу хотела сделать мн. число, но потом засомневалась из-за "а также".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, также, где я могу найти это правило. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Основу регулирования таких вопросов составляет Закон о здравоохранении, а также Закон о санитарно-эпидемиологическом благополучии".

ПРАВИЛО

Если между однородными подлежащими стоит  п р и с о е д и н и т е л ь н ы й  союз, то сказуемое согласуется с ближайшим подлежащим, например: В Бельгию экспортирован лён, а также лесные товары.

http://www.sinykova.ru/spravochnik-rozental/styli_xliii/